# Moving Data to new tab and reformatting it to make it easier to Export To Access

Tags: excel, vba

We currently have a spreadsheet that is used for scheduling, the gentleman using it doesn't want it changed so what I was thinking was create a new sheet with different formatting using VBA or a macro or?? I will then be able to import the new sheet into access where it is needed for a different program.  I am attaching 2 different pictures the first is what it looks like now and 2nd is what I would like it to look like.

Old format
[image: Old Format]
[Better picture of Old Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of8rF.png)
New format
[image: What I would Like it to be]

.  I have not done a lot of coding in Excel, normally just ='Sheet1'!E5, but didn't see how I could move the date properly and then not have the date show up any where else.  The schedule may have 1 item assigned for a day or multiple items. If I have left something out that would be helpful please let me know.

Comment: I am familiar with VBA just in Access.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly...
The old format is something like this : 
[image]

The expected result for the new format :
[image]

If that's what you mean...

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range: Dim cell As Range
Dim rgCnt As Range: Dim cnt As Long

Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)

With ActiveSheet
    .Name = "TEST"
    .Columns(1).Insert
    .Range("A1").Value = "DATE"
    Set rg = .Range("C2", .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cell In rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    Set rgCnt = Range(cell.Offset(1, 0), cell.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))
    If cell.Offset(2, 0).Value = "" Then cnt = 1 Else cnt = rgCnt.Rows.Count
    cell.Offset(1, -2).Resize(cnt, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next

rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

There is a consistent pattern in the old format, where to the right of each blank cell in column B is the date. So we use the blank cell in column B as the benchmark to get the date in column C.

The process:
it copy sheet1 where the old format is.
name the copied sheet to "TEST"
insert one column, and put the header name "DATE"
since HD-2 now is in column C (after insert one column)
so the code make a rg variable to data range in column C.

Then it loop to only the blank cell in rg
set the range to check how many data under each date into rgCnt variable
if the looped cell offset(2,0) is blank then there is only one data under the date so it make the value of cnt variable = 1
if the looped cell offset(2,0) is not blank then there is more than one data under the date, then have the value of cnt from the rgCnt rows count.
then it fill column A (DATE header) with the date as many rows defined by the cnt value.

After the loop done, it delete the entire row of all blank cell in rg variable.

Comment: I keep getting a Run-time error '1004": Insert Method of Range Class Failed Error.

Comment: Your colorful image information is not enough for me, because you don't include the name of the sheet and the starting header cell . The sub in my answer : Sheet1 and header starts in cell A1. So maybe the error because the data is not in sheet 1 or the starting header is not A1. Step run the sub and see at what line the error show.

Comment: I think I know the problem, I should have taken a better picture.  I will try and post a pic of the top rows of data as well as the data I needed.

Comment: Based on your "better" picture, Please try : change this `Set rg = .Range("C2", .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` into `Set rg = .Range("g4", .Range("g" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`. And this `cell.Offset(1, -2).Resize(cnt, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value` into `cell.Offset(1, -6).Resize(cnt, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value`. Still, you need to change the name of the sheet in the code if your "better" picture sheet name is not Sheet1. Not tested.